# Rails association within an association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, associations, simple-form, nested-attributes

I built a form so that users can add publications to my app. The `publications` table has a HABTM relationship with my `authors` table, and I have that association working in my form with this code:

`<%= f.association(:authors, as: :check_boxes, collection: Author.order('name ASC') %>`

Turns out that I need to let users select a "first author" and "last author" from that list.

To do this, I want to make two more input fields in the form that creates an association between authors and publications, but saved as `:first_author` and `:last_author` respectively.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: What's your association setup? Do you have something like Publication has_one first_author?

Comment: add these as two fields in `publications` and associate them to `author`?